# Why does Firefox display an й instead of an é?

Tags: firefox, fonts

This has bugged me for a while, but on many pages viewed with Firefox on Ubuntu (but not on Windows or OSX) any `é` (e with an acute accent) is replaced by a `й` (the Cyrillic Short I). There are probably other examples, but this is the one I encounter all the time.

Why is this, and is there anything I can do to get Firefox to display the characters properly?

A screenshot that should read résumé:

[image: résumé]

Here's an example of a page where this happens:
http://www.theonion.com/articles/company-immediately-calls-job-applicant-upon-seein,31669/

Interestingly, the title displays fine. Looking at the page source the characters that display correctly are simply `é` while those that do not are written as `&eacute`, `&amp;eacute` or `&#233` (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the character codification settings. Open the menu **Edit** | **Preferences** and select the tab **Content**. There click on the **Advanced...** button under **Fonts and Colors** (highlighted in the image, below).

[image: Content tab on Firefox Preferences]

The **Typography** window will open and there you can check/adjust the character codification. Or perhaps you would need to change any of the other settings, like default fonts or not allowing webpages to show their own fonts.

[image: Typography settings window]

---

Another possibility is that the Firefox is using the wrong character encoding for those webpages. You can check what character encoding (if any) those sites use by right-clicking anywhere on the page and selecting "View page source".

You might also want to check the settings under the menu **View** | **Character encoding** to see if the encoding selected corresponds to the one set by the webpage (here, whatever is selected would probably be different for different webpages), and under **Autodetect** to see if autodetecting is deactivated.

[image: firefox menu: autodetect character encoding]

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what I'd change, it's all set to those defaults. I can force pages to use my Serif font, and then I always get the correct characters, but then pages can look odd. And that doesn't change the fact that those websites display their own fonts fine when I use another OS.

Comment: Autoencoding is off too, and the encoding is correctly matched with the source.

Comment: Can you tell one webpage where this problem occur?

Comment: I edited the question to include one. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Have you changed your system's default fonts? I can't think a reason why your Firefox would display something associated with [encoding problems with Windows](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-HA010121249.aspx#BM1) (also, [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?158435-warning-unmappable-character-for-encoding-Cp1252&s=84d8eccc1bb9e4996a4a2df870afe44c&p=542833&viewfull=1#post542833))

Comment: Weird! I've never changed the default fonts. Though I have added some extras (like the Tibetan fonts package). I wonder if some random added font messed things up...

Comment: Well, your answer put me on the right track: apparently I added Helvetica as a font at some point (sitting in ~/.fonts). When deleted, pages view just fine. That all seems really weird to me. I though this might be a broader problem, but I guess it's pretty unique, sigh. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it's clear now what the problem was. Cheers.